# NodeJS FFI - create array of struct

Tags: node.js, ref, node-ffi

I have C++ code. How can I repeat such code using `nodejs` modules `ffi`, `ref`, `ref-struct`, `ref-array`

```
CK_BBOOL yes = CK_TRUE;
CK_BBOOL no = CK_FALSE;
// encryption/decryption sensitive key
CK_ATTRIBUTE key_template[] = {
    {CKA_SENSITIVE, &yes, sizeof(CK_BBOOL)},    // key is sensitive: should not be readable
    {CKA_ENCRYPT, &yes, sizeof(CK_BBOOL)} ,     // key can encrypt data
    {CKA_DECRYPT, &yes, sizeof(CK_BBOOL)} ,     // key can decrypt data
};

CK_OBJECT_HANDLE key;   // key handle for the new key
CK_MECHANISM gen_mec = {CKM_DES_KEY_GEN, NULL_PTR, 0};      // DES key
C_GenerateKey(session, &gen_mec, key_template, 3, &key);    // generates the key
if (rv != CKR_OK) {
    printf("Something went wrong while generating the key: %lu\n",rv);
    exit(1);
} else
    printf("Key generated!\n");
    // now key 'points' to the freshly generated key
```

For more details it's a PKCS11 functions.

My JavaScript code is

```
var Templates = RefArray(CKI.CK_ATTRIBUTE);

var valueLen = new Buffer(4);
valueLen.writeUInt32LE(32, 0);
valueLen.type = CKI.CK_ULONG; //ulong

var bTrue = new Buffer(1);
bTrue.writeUInt8(1, 0);
bTrue.type = CKI.CK_BYTE; //uchar

var template0 = new CKI.CK_ATTRIBUTE({type: CKI.CKA_SENSITIVE, pValue: bTrue.ref(), ulValueLen: 1});
var template1 = new CKI.CK_ATTRIBUTE({type: CKI.CKA_VALUE_LEN, pValue: valueLen.ref(), ulValueLen: 4});
var template2 = new CKI.CK_ATTRIBUTE({type: CKI.CKA_ENCRYPT, pValue: bTrue.ref(), ulValueLen: 1});
var template3 = new CKI.CK_ATTRIBUTE({type: CKI.CKA_DECRYPT, pValue: bTrue.ref(), ulValueLen: 1});

var templates = new Templates(4);

templates[0] = template0;
templates[1] = template2;
templates[2] = template3;
templates[3] = template1;

var $hObject = Ref.alloc(CKI.CK_ULONG);

Debug('C_GenerateKey');
var res = this.cki.C_GenerateKey(this.handle, mech.ref(), templates.ref(), 4, $hObject);
Utils.check_cki_res(res, 'C_GenerateKey');
```

After runing this code for `CKK_AES_KEY_GEN` mechanism `C_GenerateKey` returns Error
`Error on Cryptoki function C_GenerateKey. Error is TemplateIncomplete(208)`

[Example of "Array of Structs"](https://github.com/TooTallNate/ref-struct/issues/11)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my question. My error is wrong using of `ref-array` (or it's `ref-array` issue). Here is example of my array creation

```
var buf = [];

function attr(t, v, l){
    return (new CKI.CK_ATTRIBUTE({ type: t, pValue: v, ulValueLen: l })).ref()
}

buf.push(attr(CKI.CKA_CLASS, secretKey.ref(), 8));
buf.push(attr(CKI.CKA_TOKEN, bTrue.ref(), 1));
buf.push(attr(CKI.CKA_SENSITIVE, bTrue.ref(), 1));
buf.push(attr(CKI.CKA_VALUE_LEN, valueLen.ref(), 8));
buf.push(attr(CKI.CKA_KEY_TYPE, secretKey.ref(), 8));
buf.push(attr(CKI.CKA_LABEL, new Buffer("testAES"), 7));
buf.push(attr(CKI.CKA_PRIVATE, bTrue.ref(), 1));

var buf = Buffer.concat(buf);

var res = this.cki.C_GenerateKey(this.handle, mech.ref(), buf, 7, $hObject);
```

It's woking OK. I printed log to file to check it. For `pkcs11` loging I used [pkcs11-logger](https://github.com/jariq/pkcs11-logger/blob/master/README.md) (it was very helpful). Here is a log from `C_GenerateKey` function

```
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :   *** Begin attribute template ***
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :   Attribute 0
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    Attribute: 0 (CKA_CLASS)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    pValue: 0x1bc2768
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    ulValueLen: 8
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    *pValue: HEX(A826BC0100000000)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :   Attribute 1
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    Attribute: 1 (CKA_TOKEN)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    pValue: 0x1bc2788
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    ulValueLen: 1
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    *pValue: HEX(B8)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :   Attribute 2
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    Attribute: 259 (CKA_SENSITIVE)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    pValue: 0x1bc27a8
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    ulValueLen: 1
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    *pValue: HEX(B8)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :   Attribute 3
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    Attribute: 353 (CKA_VALUE_LEN)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    pValue: 0x1bc27c8
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    ulValueLen: 8
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    *pValue: HEX(A026BC0100000000)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :   Attribute 4
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    Attribute: 256 (CKA_KEY_TYPE)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    pValue: 0x1bc27e8
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    ulValueLen: 8
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    *pValue: HEX(A826BC0100000000)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :   Attribute 5
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    Attribute: 3 (CKA_LABEL)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    pValue: 0x1bc2808
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    ulValueLen: 7
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    *pValue: HEX(74657374414553)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :   Attribute 6
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    Attribute: 2 (CKA_PRIVATE)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    pValue: 0x1bc2828
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    ulValueLen: 1
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :    *pValue: HEX(B8)
0x000006e5 : 0x0708e740 :   *** End attribute template ***
```